# Grouping a array values in php

Tags: php

I have a array value's like

```
$array[0]="Test|121";
$array[1]="Test|goo";
$array[2]="Test|example";
```

I need to change this to

```
$array[0]="Test";
$array[1]="121";
$array[2]="goo";
$array[3]="example";
```

can any one tell me how can i do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) This is not difficult. Just loop through the array and change what you need to change.

Comment: Your example follows no discernible pattern. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Radu, looks like he's trying to split the values and not include duplicates. So @Ramesh try splitting the array first, then using array_unique()

Answer (score 1):

```
$array[0]="Test|121";
$array[1]="Test|goo";
$array[2]="Test|example";

$result = explode( '|', array_shift( $array));
foreach( $array as $k => $v) {
    $parts = explode( '|', $v);
    $result[] = array_pop( $parts);
}

var_dump( $result);
```

This produces the *convoluted and very odd* [output](http://viper-7.com/3Xjfbx):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "121"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "goo"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "example"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cutStr(&$elem, $key)
{
    $ret = explode('|', $elem);

    if ( $key == 0 )
        $elem = $ret[0];
    else
        $elem = $ret[1];
}

$array[0]="Test|121";
$array[1]="Test|goo";
$array[2]="Test|example";

array_walk($array, 'cutStr');
print_r($array);
```

try this.

Comment: This will fail as `121` will never be in the array.